# Adjective meaning something has been said with a lot of authority

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I'm looking for an adjective qualifying something said with a lot of authority, i.e. that the person saying it is very qualified for or familiar with the subject.

I want use it in a sentence such as "I don't fully understand your answer but [due to its many complicated and technical terms] it seems to be very <insert adjective here>."

Comment: "Property" isn't the word here. Perhaps "authority", but that's a little bit more limited than what I think you want.

Comment: @chrylis I see. I think "authority" fits well in this case.

Comment: @chrylis BTW, I meant it for someone who (probably) is not the creator/maintainer of an open-source software tool but knows a lot about its inner workings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about [*informed*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/informed)?

> I don't fully understand your answer, but it seems to be very informed.

Answer (score 8):

> the person saying it is very qualified for or familiar with the
>   subject.

An answer given by such person could be called ***authoritative***:

> **authoritative** - *able to be trusted as being accurate or true; reliable : clear, authoritative information and advice | an
>   authoritative source.*

New Oxford American Dictionary

Comment: Good answer -- now I'm in doubt whether I was looking for *informed* or *authoritative*... but staying with *informed* seems more suited for my context.

Answer (score 1):

You may use ***[erudite](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/erudite)***:

> - Having or showing great knowledge or learning. (AHD)
> - having or containing a lot of knowledge that is known by very few people. (Cambridge Dictionary)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It's not the word I was trying to remember but I figured out after looking for synonyms that the word is **informed**.

Comment: LOL literally just now commented that

Comment: I'm going to accept it. However I don't understand why upvoting this one was not possible (or perhaps someone has downvoted it).

Comment: Can't speak for whoever downvoted you, but I do want to note that erudite describes the _person_ as one who is knowledgeable, not the answer.

Comment: @AleksandrH - I think it may be used referring to questions or answers: From: Great Britain. Parliament. House of Commons - 1980- 
Whether I shall be able to give him a satisfactory ***reply to such an erudite question is a different matter***. The hon. Member for Isle of Ely described himself as the Liberal spokesman for Friday. Members of other parties, unfortunately, have to take ...https://books.google.it/books?id=4MctAAAAYAAJ&q=%22erudite+question%22&dq=%22erudite+question%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjWiPL2utjPAhVEtRQKHdKrD28Q6AEIGzAA

Comment: I see, in that case I think your answer's just as fine

Answer (score 1):

How about *expert*?

From M-W:

> [*expert*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/expert): having
>   or showing special skill or knowledge because of what you have been
>   taught or what you have experienced

You example:

> "I don't fully understand your answer but [due to its many complicated
>   and technical terms] it seems to be very *expert*."

*Expert* lines up well with one of your comments:

> "I meant it for someone who (probably) is not the creator/maintainer
>   of an open-source software tool but knows a lot about its inner
>   workings."

Your *someone* is displaying special skill or knowledge based on what he or she has been taught, or more likely, experienced.